# Program ends after user input is invalid

Tags: c#, message

How would make the program state that the users input is invalid and then close after enter is pressed? I have the first error that states that the value the user inputted is wrong, giving them another try, but if the user types the same/invalid number it will repeat the last thing. How can I make it limit to one more try and then if the user doesn't give a valid entry it would right and error? The code is below:

```
        string First;
        string Last;
        First = "Cristiano";
        Last = " Ronaldo";
        Console.Write("Please enter student name <First Last>: ");
        Console.WriteLine(First + Last);

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        Console.WriteLine("*************NOTE**********************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("*** Be sure to include decimal point for scores.            ***");
        Console.WriteLine("***     !!!All score should range from 0.00 to 100.00 !!    ***");
        Console.WriteLine("***                                                         ***");
        Console.WriteLine("*** For example : 80.50                                     ***");
        Console.WriteLine("***************************************************************");

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        double Exam_1 = -1;
        double Exam_2;
        double Exam_3;
        double Assignment_1;
        double Assignment_2;

        Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 1 <Example: 100.0>: ");
        Exam_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        while (Exam_1 < 0.0 || Exam_1 > 100.0)
        {
            Console.Write("Exam score cannot be less than 0. or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Exam 1 <Example: 95.0>:");
            Exam_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 2 <Example: 0.0>: ");
        Exam_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        while (Exam_2 < 0.0 || Exam_2 > 100.0)
        {
            Console.Write("Exam score cannot be less than 0.0 or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Exam 2 <Example: 95.0>:");
            Exam_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 3 <Example: 60.8>: ");
        Exam_3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        while (Exam_3 < 0.0 || Exam_3 > 100.0)
        {
            Console.Write("Exam score cannot be less than 0.0 or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Exam 3 <Example: 95.0>:");
            Exam_3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        Console.Write("Please enter score for Assignment 1 <Example: 100.0>: ");
        Assignment_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        while (Assignment_1 < 0.0 || Exam_2 > 100.0)
        {
            Console.Write("Assignment score cannot be less than 0.0 or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Assignment 1 <Example: 95.0>:");
            Assignment_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.Write("Please enter score for Assignment 2 <Example: 23.46>: ");
        Assignment_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        while (Assignment_2 < 0.0 || Assignment_2 > 100.0)
        {
            Console.Write("Assignment score can not be less than 0.0 or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Assignment 2 <Example: 56.0>: ");
            Assignment_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        Console.WriteLine(" -------------- OUTPUT ---------------");

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        Console.Write("Student: ");
        Console.WriteLine(First + Last);

        Console.WriteLine(" ");



















        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string First;
        string Last;
        First = "Cristiano";
        Last = " Ronaldo";
        Console.Write("Please enter student name <First Last>: ");
        Console.WriteLine(First + Last);

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        Console.WriteLine("*************NOTE**********************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("*** Be sure to include decimal point for scores.            ***");
        Console.WriteLine("***     !!!All score should range from 0.00 to 100.00 !!    ***");
        Console.WriteLine("***                                                         ***");
        Console.WriteLine("*** For example : 80.50                                     ***");
        Console.WriteLine("***************************************************************");

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        double Exam_1 = -1;
        double Exam_2;
        double Exam_3;
        double Assignment_1;
        double Assignment_2;

        Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 1 <Example: 100.0>: ");
        Exam_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        var exitProgram = false;
        var errorCount = 0;

        while (Exam_1 < 0.0 || Exam_1 > 100.0)
        {
            Console.Write("Exam score cannot be less than 0. or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Exam 1 <Example: 95.0>:");
            Exam_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            ++errorCount;
            ErrorCount(errorCount);
        }

        Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 2 <Example: 0.0>: ");
        Exam_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        errorCount = 0;
        while (Exam_2 < 0.0 || Exam_2 > 100.0)
        {
            Console.Write("Exam score cannot be less than 0.0 or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Exam 2 <Example: 95.0>:");
            Exam_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            ++errorCount;
            ErrorCount(errorCount);
        }

        Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 3 <Example: 60.8>: ");
        Exam_3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        errorCount = 0;
        while (Exam_3 < 0.0 || Exam_3 > 100.0)
        {
            Console.Write("Exam score cannot be less than 0.0 or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Exam 3 <Example: 95.0>:");
            Exam_3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            ++errorCount;
            ErrorCount(errorCount);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        Console.Write("Please enter score for Assignment 1 <Example: 100.0>: ");
        Assignment_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        errorCount = 0;
        while (Assignment_1 < 0.0 || Exam_2 > 100.0)
        {
            Console.Write("Assignment score cannot be less than 0.0 or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Assignment 1 <Example: 95.0>:");
            Assignment_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            ++errorCount;
            ErrorCount(errorCount);
        }

        Console.Write("Please enter score for Assignment 2 <Example: 23.46>: ");
        Assignment_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        errorCount = 0;
        while (Assignment_2 < 0.0 || Assignment_2 > 100.0)
        {
            Console.Write("Assignment score can not be less than 0.0 or greater than 100.0. Please re-enter the score for Assignment 2 <Example: 56.0>: ");
            Assignment_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            ++errorCount;
            ErrorCount(errorCount);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        Console.WriteLine(" -------------- OUTPUT ---------------");

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        Console.Write("Student: ");
        Console.WriteLine(First + Last);

        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void ErrorCount(int errorCount)
    {
        if (errorCount > 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Error count too much ! . . . ");
            Console.Write("Press any key to exit . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

    }
```

Bear in mind it doesn't detect if the user enters an alpha numeric number or special characters but you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Given this is an assignment, I am not sure if your professor was anything like mine where we could only use what we have learned in class. That said, you might want to look into double.tryparse https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx

The function will return a bool if the input was parsable as a double and false if the input was invalid. The code example on the MSDN linke above should give you a great start.

Answer (score 3):

You are obviously new to the coding world and this looks suspiciously like a homework question. However, I suspect the problem you have highlighted is rooted in the fact that when you call `Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())` where the input cannot be converted an Exception is thrown and you aren't catching it.

You can read more about Exceptions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx

To fix, I would implement something like this:

```
Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 1 <Example: 100.0>: ");
while(!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Exam_1))
{
      Console.Write("Try again...");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the logic of your code.  A while loop will continuously loop until the expression evaluates to false.  If you wish to terminate the loop early, you will need to modify your loop by altering the conditional expression, using a different type of loop, or using a break statement.

[Here is some reference material from Microsoft's website.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147286(v=vs.88).aspx#Looping)

Think through your problem and ask yourself: How would you do this if you were doing this manually?  What logical steps would you take if you were in the computer's place?  What decisions would you make and what information would you need to make those decisions?